# Best way to check a variable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which checks is a variable is set or is equal to 'no'. If it is equal to no or is not set, it defines the var to be 'yes'.

This is my code

```
if (typeof progress == 'undefined' || progress == 'no') { 
document.getElementById('button-play').onclick = null;
var progress = 'yes';
```

Then a function is called which overwrites the variable to be no.

```
function enableButton(){
var progress = 'no';
document.getElementById('button-play').onclick = play();
}
```

The first time when executing the script and progress is undefined, the script works, and does overwrite progress to 'no', but when I try to run the script again with var progress defined as 'no' it does not work.

Am I checking the value of progress correctly?

Added jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zxxubopq/

Comment: you should add a code snippet from jsfiddle/codepen so we can help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scope` in Javascript is either **Global** or **Function**. If you define a variable in `function`, it'll be scoped in that `function` only.

That does not override the varible, it is a different, local `progress` variable in the scope of `enableButton()`. You should fix your scopes, and it will work.

---

Edit after your comment:

```
document.getElementById('button-play').onclick = play();
```

is actually wrong, because you want to assign the function to `onclick`, not the return value, so you actually need:

```
document.getElementById('button-play').onclick = play;
```

Remember, JavaScript functions are first-class functions, so they can be treated just like any other object.

Comment: I added jsfiddle, could you show me how to manage the scopes? Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/zxxubopq/

Comment: Ugly, but this works: https://jsfiddle.net/zxxubopq/1/ You should try not to use globals, if possible.

Comment: A better solution would be: https://jsfiddle.net/zxxubopq/4/ (no more global scope pollution)

Comment: Okay, i did this and it worked. To re enable the inline onclick I added `document.getElementById('button-play').onclick = play();` What this does now is loop the play() function over and over every 4 seconds. https://jsfiddle.net/zxxubopq/7/  Do you know how to stop this spam?

Comment: I decided to use your first model until I can fix the script spam. https://jsfiddle.net/zxxubopq/7/

Answer (score 2):

Your `var` inside a function makes the variable `progress` a local one. So any changes to the local variable don't apply for the global one.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/zxxubopq/. Could you maybe show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
function enableButton(){
  var progress = 'no';
}
```

This line of code creates new variable `var progress` inside function. So when function exits this variable is deleted.

Try to change it to:

```
function enableButton(){
    progress = 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable 'progress' outside both function at start.